# C - как изменить символ в string путём изменения её ASCII кода?

Tags: c, строки, ascii, cs50

Например:

```
int i = 'A';
k = i + 1;
printf("%i %c\n%i %c", i, i, k, k)
```

на выходе мы должны получить:

65  A

66  B

а как сделать тоже самое с string?

Comment: А вы доступ к элементам строки уже умеете получать?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду string t = "abc"; printf(t[0])==> a ?

Comment: Ага. И что вам мешало попробовать увеличить элемент строки?

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю о чём вы...

Comment: вы имеете в виду t[0] = t[0]++?

Comment: Зачем вы спрашиваете, если компилятор и выполнение ответят быстрее?

Comment: ок, я кажется разобрался, спасибо. CS50 видимо иногда не объясняет базовых вещей либо я плохо ищу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` в cs50 это [указатель на `char`](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/2eccace2089b9342ff118262390b0579c9a72f2f/src/cs50.h#L48-L51).

Если строка указывает на изменяемую память, то можно в ней символ изменить так же как и в массиве `char`, [пример (нажмите <kbd>Forward ></kbd> кнопку)](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=%23include%20%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aint%20main%28void%29%20%7B%0A%20%20char%20s%5B%5D%20%3D%20u8%22abc%22%3B%0A%20%20s%5B0%5D%20%2B%3D%201%3B%0A%20%20return%20printf%28%22%25s%5Cn%22,%20s%29%20%3C%200%3B%0A%7D&cumulative=false&curInstr=1&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=c&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char s[] = u8"abc";
  s[0] += 1;
  return printf("%s\n", s) < 0;
}
```

Индексация `s[i]` (получить `i`-тый элемент) работает как для массивов так и для указателей (равнозначно `*(s + i)`), то есть выражение `s[0] += 1` может работать и для string типа.

`c += 1` ~равнозначен `c = c + 1`. `char` в арифметических операциях до int (или до unsigned) повышается. Численные значения символов в `s` равны соответствующим численным значениям их кодов (байт):

```
char s[] = {97, 98, 99, 0};
```

поэтому `s[0] += 1` равнозначен `s[0] = 98` здесь. Если кодировка вашего окружения совместима с ascii, то при выводе байта `98` он будет показан как `b` буква.

Обратите внимание:

- `string word = "a to b"` не используется, так как попытка изменить `word[i]` по месту привела бы к "undefined behavior". Строковые константы неизменяемы в Си
- используется `char[]`, чтобы данные были скопированы из константы в массив, чтобы можно было безопасно их изменить
- используется `u8""` константа, чтобы переносимый результат получить (чтобы `abc` буквы в байты превращались, используя UTF-8 кодировку, которая совпадает с ascii для этих символов). Иначе нет гарантии, что коды `a-z` латинских букв подряд идут.

Answer (score 1):

Если кто-то будет искать ответ на вопрос:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>


int main()
{
    string word = "a to b";
    char s;
    s=word[0]+1;
    printf("%c\n", s);
}
```

На выходе будет b

Comment: А в чем здесь ответ на вопрос?